# How to "clean-up" string data in given format so a dictionary can be created from it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string such as the format below that I want to clean-up and put into a dictionary for further processing.
In my initial (hackish) attempt, I tried replacing some characters of the string and then create a dictionary using dict(), but this results in an error.

```
string = '(.(."Key1", "Value1"), (."Key2", "Value2"))'
string = string.replace('(.', '(')
string = string.replace('((', '(')
string = string.replace('))', ')')
Dict = dict([string])
```

Searching similar queries on this site mention using `json.loads()` instead of `dict()`, but I have not had success using that method either.

Comment: What's the context for this strange format?

Comment: @HélitonMartins No its not, only square brackets `[]` works

Comment: Welcome to SO! When posting parsing questions, it's important to clarify exactly what we're parsing here. Otherwise, it can be endless assumptions and kick-the-can/moving-goalposts. Is the string you show arbitrarily recursive? What characters are valid for the keys and values? What's the significance of the leading `(.` syntax? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @SuperStormer sorry, my bad

Comment: What happened when you tried reading the documentation for `dict`? What do you think the structure that you pass to it should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would only need to do a minimal amount of "cleaning-up" to turn the string into a valid Python literal and then use the [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function to actual turn it into a usable value (a tuple-of-tuples). Afterwards you can pass that to the `dict` class to construct a dictionary.

```
import ast

string = '(.(."Key1", "Value1"), (."Key2", "Value2"))'

string = string.replace('(.', '(')  # Replace '(.' with '('.
pairs = ast.literal_eval(string)
result = dict(pairs)
print(result)  # -> {'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2'}
```

Answer (score 4):

Regular expressions are handy here:

```py
>>> import re
>>> string = '(.(."Key1", "Value1"), (."Key2", "Value2"))'
>>> kv_pairs = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)",\s*"([^"]*)"', string)
>>> kv_pairs
[('Key1', 'Value1'), ('Key2', 'Value2')]
>>> dict(kv_pairs)
{'Key1': 'Value1', 'Key2': 'Value2'}
```

Comment: Nice. You can also ignore the ```(.``` completely. ```r'"([^"]*)"\s*,\s*"([^"]*)"'```

Comment: @jwal Good suggestion

Comment: A regex seems like overkill to me to do something this simple.

Answer (score 0):

I would first replace `(.` with `(`, do a simple regex to find the key-value pairs and finally construct dictionary using comprehension.

```py
import re

string = '(.(."Key1", "Value1"), (."Key2", "Value2"))'

# first replace (. with (
string = string.replace('(.', '(') 

# then find key-value pairs using regex
kv_pairs = re.findall(r'\("(\w+)",\s*"(\w+)"\)', string)
#                            |          |
#                       matches key   matches value

# finally construct dictionary using comprehension
result_dict = {k:v for k, v in kv_pairs}
```